# set focus on grid control in uwp programmatically

Tags: c#, uwp, focus, grid-layout

I am having a Grid control with a KeyUp handler attached to it in an UWP application. On this grid I am having a button. When clicking the button, the button keeps the focus. As a result the keystroke events are not handled by the handler attached to the grid. This is undesired behaviour in my application.

If I click manually on the grid, it will get focus and keyevents work again, which is desired behaviour. I want to solve this programmatically. I was thinking to solve this by implementing in the button click event code that will set the focus to the grid again.

Came up with this document
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control.focus

So I expected to be able to write `Grid.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);`
However, the Focus method doesn't exist on the Grid control.

Anybody knows what I'm doing wrong or how this can be solved otherwise?

Simplified example of XAML

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" x:Name="Grid" KeyUp="Grid_KeyUp">
    <Button Content="MP3" Margin="5" Click="btnOpenMP3_Click" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

> set focus on grid control in uwp programmatically

Derive from this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58908845/keydown-event-doesnt-trigger-from-selected-grid-in-uwp) :

> The key down event only trigger from keyboard focused control. And the Grid is not a control and the Grid is Panel. In UWP, only the control can set focus.

Please try to write a empty control and add it to the Grid, then set the control focus programmatically.

For detail steps please refer above case link.

Comment: Thx, I will give that a try.

However, reacting to ‘the key down event only trigger from keyboard focus control’. The keydown does get triggered from the grid. Also after using a button, if I click manually on the grid (I.e. not on another control) the keydown event handler of the grid gets triggered. 

So apparently keydowns come in, however I cannot mimick the manual behaviour of clicking on the grid.

Comment: Does above reply solved your issue and have any updates?

Comment: I gave it a try and as expected this works. I was hoping for something more elegant that mimics user behaviour: if you click as a user on the grid (i.e. non on another control) the keyup events will work again. Apparantly this cannot  be mimiced in the current state of the framework. I think that is an omission. The behavior evidently is in the grid component

Comment: It's by design, if you do want this feature, please feel free post your requirement with Windows Feed Back Hub app.